# Implement versioning of a RESTful API with PHP/Slim and Apache

Tags: php, apache, rest, .htaccess, slim

#### **Following some comments I create a question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215755).**

---

I want to create a RESTful API with Apache/PHP and the Slim Framework (3.x). The API should support URI-based versioning like `<host>/rest/api/v1/<resource>` and `<host>/rest/api/latest/<resource>`.

Overall I found a solution which works, but I not really happy with my solution and I'm want to known what can I make better. I'm a rookie/newbie about Slim. I'm looking for new ideas and how I can improve my knowledge about Slim.

- General improvements or comments?
- Do you have a better/simpler solution?
- Do you see problems in my solution?
- Improvements for .htaccess / rewrite rules
- Links to real implementations of a RESTful API with Slim
- ....

I'm looking forward for your answers and I'll be curious to see what's new.

---

Every new version should be a new project, which a own independent code base. The version dispatching should be done by the Apache server and no in the PHP/Slim code. I found some example which implements different versions of the API in on project by using the group-method. But I'm not very happy with this solution. I feel better to have independent projects for independent versions.

I create a folder/file structure in htdocs folder like this:

```
rest
 +--api
     +-v1
        +-.htaccess
        +-api.php
     +-v2
        +-.htaccess
        +-api.php
     +-.htaccess
```

The implementation of the API are in the file `api.php`. Map calls like `/rest/api/v1/books` to my implementation I create in every version folder a `.htaccess` file which includes rules for the rewrite Apache module:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^$ / [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ api.php [QSA,L]
```

The first rewrite rule is need to match the call `/rest/api/v1` and the second rule rewrites paths like  `/rest/api/v1/books` to the implementation.

In `api.php` I create some routes

```
$app->get('/books', function ...
$app->get('/books/{id}', function ...
```

Everything works fine if I use a explicit version in the URI (`<host>/rest/api/v2/books`). For convenience if I create an alias *latest* (`/rest/api/latest/books`), which redirect the alias-call to the latest version of the API version.

Therefore I create the file `rest/api/.htaccess` which rewrites the URI to an implementation:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^latest.*$ ./v2/api.php [QSA,L]
```

The rewrite rule works fine and the v2 implementation are called. But the routes don't match anymore. I found out that the original path is now part of the path.

```
/rest/api/v2/books -> /books
/rest/api/latest/books -> /rest/api/latest/books
```

If I modified the rules like this, it works - but I don't like to implement every rule twice.

```
$app->get('/rest/api/latest/books', function ...
$app->get('/rest/api/latest/books/{id}', function ...
```

Therefore I wrote a middleware function which trims `/rest/api/latest` from the path before the routes are matched.

```
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $path = $uri->getPath();
    if (substr($path,0,16) == "/rest/api/latest") {
        $uri = $uri->withPath(substr($path,16));
        return $next($request->withUri($uri), $response);
    }
    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Now I can use the same rules for both cases, explicit version call and implicit version call.

Comment: You should ask all of these questions on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As previous comment says, your question seems too broad and off-topic for SO. But since we're here, I'm curious why do you feel better to have independent projects instead of grouping routes? I mean can you explain you decision in details? Did you try to group routes? It seems you're causing yourself too much trouble just to get away from grouped routes method, which is actually a pretty convenient solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I create a question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215755)